# Как вывести только чётные/нечётные числа из списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Начал учить питон, нужно вывести все чётные/нечётные числа от 1 до введённого(input), на экран. Пытался "вырвать" числа через одно, но выдаёт ошибку "builtins.TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable". Искал в интернете, как выводить только чётные/нечётные числа, ничего в моей ситуации не подошло. Заранее спасибо добрым людям за помощь!

```
n = int(input())
k = int(input())
if k == 1:
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        print(i[:1], end=' ')
```

Comment: Число считается четным, если оно делится на 2, то есть его остаток от деления на 2 равен 0. В Python есть прекрасный оператор `%`. Он - тот, кто вам нужен

Comment: А что в этом коде выводит через одно?

Comment: `n = int(input()); k = int(input()); print(*range(k, n + 1, 2))`

Answer (score 1):

Вы, наверно, имели в виду

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(1, n + 1, 2):
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Заметьте параметр `2` в функции `range()`.

(Т.к. `i` целое число, **а не список,** невозможно к нему применить отрезок `[:1]`, как вы сделали в своей программе и что вызвало ошибку.
Для версии с применением отрезка см. конец этого ответа.)

---

*Объяснение:*

Число 2 как 3-ий параметр в функции `range(1, n + 1, 2)` определяет **шаг**, т.е. она будет выдавать

- каждый `2-ой` элемент из диапазона `1, 2, 3, ... n`

т.е. числа **1, 3, 5,** и т.д.

Когда бы вы хотели выводить наоборот **четные** числа, примените `range(2, n + 1, 2)`.

---

*Примечание:*

Может быть, что вы хотели сначала из `range(1, n + 1)` сделать **список**, чтобы была возможность применить *отрезки* (`[]`):

```
n = int(input())
lst = list(range(1, n + 1))
print(lst[::2])
```

Отрезки подобны функции `range()` (`[откуда:докуда:шаг]`) - я пропустил «откуда» и «докуда», чтобы применить только «шаг» (на весь список).

(Для вывода четных чисел вместо `range(1, n + 1)` примените `range(2, n + 1)`.)

Answer (score 0):

Для четных чисел:

```
f = int(input())
for i in range(1, f)
if i % 2 == 0:
   print(i, end = ' ')
```

Для нечетных чисел:

```
f = int(input())
for i in range(1, f)
if i % 2 != 0:
   print(i, end = ' ')
```

Comment: а чем ваш ответ отличается от предыдущего помимо того, что вы пропустили отступы перед if, обрабатываете в два раза больше чисел, и выполняете вдобавок проверку на [не]чётность?

Answer (score 0):

```
for number in range(1, 21, 2):
    print(number)
```

вывод:

```
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
```